# Can the subject be an adjective phrase, adverb phrase, or a bare infinitival clause?

Tags: subjects, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases, bare-infinitives

This is an exercise in Chapter 5 of a textbook by Bas Aarts, *English Syntax and Argumentation*, 4th edition, published 2013, on page 88:

> 8. In previous editions of this book I allowed for adjective phrases, adverb phrases and bare infinite clauses to function as Subject, and I used the examples below to illustrate these possibilities:
>
>    (i) [ <sub>AP</sub> *Restless*] is what I would call him.
>
>    (ii) [ <sub>AdvP</sub> *Cautiously*] is how I would suggest you do it.
>
>    (iii) [ <sub>bare inf. clause</sub> *Party the night away*] is a nice thing to do.
>
> However, the italicized strings in these examples are best not taken to be Subjects. Why not? Review Section 2.1 to remind yourself of the distributional properties of Subjects.

---

I don't know how to answer this question.

If you have the book *English Syntax and Argumentation*, 3th or 4th edition, please help me to answer this question. 
Even if you don't have that book, of course you can help me.

Comment: Because they're clunky, unwieldy and not natural English. They're not completely unused, just uncommon.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.amazon.com/English-Argumentation-Palgrave-Linguistics-Paperback/dp/B00RWS3VRC/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1427524284&sr=1-1&keywords=English+Syntax+and+Argumentation+4th) the book?

Comment: Especially #3.  I would call it ungrammatical as well as clunky.  "Party**ing*** the night away. . ." would be grammatical.

Comment: I've never read the book, and I don't have it, but I think it's more common to think of *what I would call him* (rather than *Restless*) in *Restless is what I would call him* as the subject of the sentence. If that sounds strange, try to think of the sentence as an alternate version of *What I would call him is restless.*

Comment: +1. That be a very good question! I know someone who ought to be interested in helping to solve this mystery! I'll go and give him a ping. :)

Comment: +1 :) Do you have a page number please?

Comment: Be aware that other grammarians and linguists might differ in their opinions here -- as Bas Aarts did himself between editions of his own textbook! Aside: the 2002 *CGEL* has examples of bare infinitivals as subject, though in informal style, on page 1254, [12], e.g. [12.ii] *"Seek professional advice is what we should do."*

Comment: The 2002 *CGEL* gives this as an example of an AdjP as subject, on page 536: *"Rather more humble is how I'd like him to be."* And for an AdvP as subject, it gives a somewhat marginal example on page 569: *"How long was spent on the job?"* There might be other related examples in various textbooks, especially in their sections on cleft constructions. :)

Comment: In Bas Aarts' book, on page 13 (the end of section 2.1), there are a bunch of tests/criteria that are given, and they might be related to what the exercise wants--though I'm not sure. Here's an idea, perhaps consider writing an answer post yourself, where you try to solve the exercise, and we'll then look at your argumentation and stuff, and critique it a bit? :)

Comment: *Wot?* Are there no linguistics students or grad students or other creatures ( @Araucaria )  that are interested in delving into this sort of rainy day topic? Is it not a rainy day somewhere on the globe? :)

Comment: @Araucaria And so, have you discussed this with B.A. as to why he changed his opinion? And would you like to share that info with the rest of us? :D

Comment: @F.E. Not yet, will do but not around right now (Easter hols), so might take a wee while ...

Comment: @F.E. Though there is this data: *Robbers **is** what they are, isn't **it***? and also *Is party the night away a nice thing to do*? which seems a bit wonky to my ear

Comment: Where be that *TEFL-teaching, crossword-guzzling postgrad linguistics* drunkard?

Comment: They're all subjects by virtue of their being clefts of one sort or another. The various clefting rules move some  focus element on one side or the other of some fulcrum of cleavage, and stuff the rest of the sentence into some pattern on the other side. Viz _He mowed the lawn ==> What he mowed was the lawn ~ It was the lawn that he mowed ~ It was he that mowed the lawn ~ The lawn is what he mowed ~ What he did was mow the lawn ~ Mow the lawn is what he did_, etc. Whether they're "real" subjects is between you and your syntactic confessor.

Comment: Aarts has not stated that he now considers the example sentences to be ungrammatical, but that he has changed his opinion on whether adjective phrases, adverb phrases, and bare infinitival clauses in such 'subject-looking' slots should actually be regarded as subjects. // I used to think that Aarts had a commendable (I'm not saying necessarily accurate) syntacto-semantic approach to these issues, but his argument here that distribution weighs against these forms being true subjects has me puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is "Can the subject be an adjective phrase, adverb phrase, or a bare infinitival clause?"

I think technically the answer is that an infinitive can be a subject, as in "To live is to suffer," but that adjectival phrases and adverb phrases can not be a "subject" as that concept is usually understood.

In your examples (i) and (ii), the subject of those sentences is "I."

> Restless is what I would call him.
>   Cautiously is how I would suggest you do it.

Re example (iii), the subject could be "to party the night away." as in  is

> To party the night away is a nice thing to do.

In examples (i) and (ii), it might help in thinking of this kind of construction to imagine quote marks around Restless and Cautiously, as in:

> "Restless" is what I would call him.
>   "Cautiously" is how I would suggest you do it.

You probably wouldn't actually write it with the quote marks, but it helps to understand how this would be spoken and what it means. These two sentences are good idiomatic sentences.

However, "Party the night away is a nice thing to do" is not idiomatic at all. It would be puzzling to a listener/reader. "To party the night away is a nice thing to do" works grammatically, though it doesn't flow very well.

Answer (score -1):

This question has two answers: a simple answer, and a complicated answer.

First, the simple answer the author of this book is clearly fishing for. The author thinks you should avoid using these constructions because, in the example sentence given, changing the subject of the sentence also allows you to change the sentence from the **passive voice** to the **active voice.** So, instead of:

> Restless is what I would call him.

the author wants you to say:

> I would call him restless.

The passive voice is a bugbear for many proscriptive grammarians. Overuse of the passive can be a real problem, but the passive voice, if not abused, can also be a useful and expressive part of the English language. A grammarian might not call these sentences part of the classic "passive voice" (his examples contain mostly predicate adjective phrases, not passive verbs), but to a rhetoritician, which I assume this author is, they have the same effect.

Now for the more complicated (and more interesting) answer. We'll take this in two parts.

First: there is absolutely nothing wrong with using an infinitive as the subject of a sentence.

> To know him is to love him.

This is straightforward and idiomatic. On the other hand, using a **bare** infinitive:

> * Know him is to love him

is not idiomatic in American or British English. The author's third example sentence will just sound wrong to most native speakers. Not awkward, but wrong, like using the wrong tense or number. I have no idea why the author would ever have thought a bare infinitive could be the subject of a sentence--or, at least, why this would be an acceptable example of it.

Ajdectives and adverbs can be sentence subjects, but doing this means something. At a minimum, it shifts the emphasis of the sentence.

> Was she pretty? No, not pretty. Striking is what I would call her.

This is a perfectly idiomatic English construction; but it has a different feel, and a different emphasis, than:

> Was she pretty? No, not pretty. I would call her striking.

In other words: the real answer is that the author wants you to avoid these passive or passive-like constructions because he or she is trying to oversimplify a complex feature of English grammar.

Comment: a) There are no passives in these sentences, though it is true (and a useful thing to point out) that one function of these constructions is the same sort of "information packaging" the passive aims at. b) The bare infinitive is grammatical, and colloquial. It is licensed as the referent of pro-verb *do* at the end, which bears the necessary *to* marker: *A fun thing to do is party all night* → *Party all night is a fun thing to do*.

Comment: A fun thing to do is to party all night. Partying all night is a fun thing to do.   Not to say one couldn't say it with the bare infinitive, but some of us wouldn't, when there are more natural-sounding ways available.

Comment: "Dance the night away sounds good to me."

Comment: "Who wants to have pizza and who wants to have burgers?  --Have pizza's my choice!"

Answer (score -1):

For the first two, they are not the subjects because they are actually the *direct objects*.

> Restless is what I would call him.

In this sentence "I" is doing an action ("call"), "restless" is what "I" called, and "him" is the indirect object that received the calling.

The last one is a poor example.

> [to] Party the night away is a nice thing to do.

In this case "party the night away" really is the subject.

In all three cases, especially the last, it is appropriate to use quotation marks due to the atypical usage.

> "Party the night away" is a nice thing to do.

We aren't actually necessarily quoting someone, but the quotation marks let us know that the verb refers to the entire phrase "party the night away". Similarly the second example:

> "Cautiously" is how I would suggest you do it.

I'm actually talking about the *concept* of the word "cautiously".

Comment: "For the first two, they are not the subjects because they are actually the *direct objects*." <== Could you please show us (in your answer post) how they are actually "direct objects"?